# Aspectj in spring

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am getting the following error when i try to auto wire aspectj in spring

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "aop" for element "aop:aspectj-autoproxy" is not bound.
```

my appContext.xml entry looks like 
.....

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<bean id="helloFromAspectJ" class="com.cvs.esps.aspect.logging.TestAspect"/>
```

.....

some help on how can i remove this error.. unfortunately the site http://forum.springsource.org is blocked by out network firewall.. any help fast will be highly appreciated.

---

here is what i get if i add the line

```
<bean id="loggerProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator" />

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf': Cannot create inner bean 'cxf:logging#d306dd' of type [org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature] while setting bean property 'features' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf:logging#d306dd': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut doPostGetPatientDataJSON
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:702)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf': Cannot create inner bean 'cxf:logging#d306dd' of type [org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature] while setting bean property 'features' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf:logging#d306dd': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut doPostGetPatientDataJSON
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.getBus(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf:logging#d306dd': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut doPostGetPatientDataJSON
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:219)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut doPostGetPatientDataJSON
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:189)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:244)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:278)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 25):

Do you have a namespace declaration in your  tag?  Something like this:

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
...>
```

Comment: http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd

I added these 2 lines in the appContext.xml

Comment: You mean you had them and it still didn't work?  Or you've added them and it does now?

Comment: Mind that the order of xsi:schemaLocation items does matter: each namespace URI should be followed by its XSD location. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062186/spring-aop-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-aopconfig

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it by arranging namespace and schemalocation as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"
        default-destroy-method="destroy"
        default-init-method="afterPropertiesSet"
        default-autowire="byName"
>
```

Notice that the schemalocation contains both uri:s, the one declared for xmlns:aop and the one for the xsd-file

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You can define the namespace for AOP in your xml file.......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
```

copy and paste the aop lines

Answer (score 0):

You have the namespace declaration for aop but you lack the xsi:schemaLocation for the aop as well. check the 'context' schema usage (it appears also in the schemaLocation)

Answer (score 0):

Please convert your project to `aspectj` project by downloading `aspectj` jars and copying them to eclipse plugin and feature folders correspondingly.

When you do this then restart `Eclipse`, right click on project and you will find some `aspecj Tools` option over there then you can convert to `aspectj` selecting source as `aspectj`.