# Spring AOP: "no declaration can be found for element 'aop:config' "

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I've seen that a few instances of this problem have been raised already. However, I am confident that I satisfy the criteria that has been outlined in those solutions. i.e. I'm pretty sure I have the desired jars on my class path + my schemalocation addresses look in order.

One solution mentioned that the issue can be caused by having another XML parser on the classpath. I do have dom4j on my classpath but I have removed it to test, and the problem persists.

Here's my classpath:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/jaxen-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.test-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RC1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/spring-mvc-airline/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.9b2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/mybatis-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/mybatis-spring-1.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/lambdaj-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/cglib-2.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/aspectj-1.6.12.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/aspectjrt-1.5.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/user/workspace/rugby-project/lib/spring-aop-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

And here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="timer" class="ie.ucd.dec.al.rugby.aop.Timer" />

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="timer">
            <aop:pointcut id="migrationManager_migrate"
                expression="execution(* ie.ucd.dec.al.rugby.data.migrate.MigrationManager.migrateAllXmlFilesInDirectory())" />

            <aop:around pointcut-ref="migrationManager_migrate"
                method="timeJob()" />
        </aop:aspect>

    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

Finally, here is my stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main"
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 15 in XML document from class path resource [spring-aop.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:config'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at ie.ucd.dec.al.rugby.data.migrate.MigrationRunner.main(MigrationRunner.java:10)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:config'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(UnknownSource)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: I have reformatted your stacktrace. Please make sure to do that by yourself next time. :-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The order of `xsi:schemaLocation` items is wrong, each namespace URI should be followed by its XSD location:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans             
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd          
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop         
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"
```

Comment: I am a good bit more Spring aware these days, and would like to advise people to use the 'Namespaces' tab within STS (Spring perspective) when adding namespaces. Removes the potential for such rookie errors.

Comment: does the version is mandatory in the declaration of the namespace ? for exemple can i put `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` instead of `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd`